# What are the prime ideals of the polynomial ring $\mathbb{R}[x]$?

Tags: irreducible-polynomials, maximal-and-prime-ideals

**The exact question is:**

[image]

**And the solution is** 
[image]

What I don't get in this solution is the circled part. Why are there no other irreducible polynomials in $\mathbb{R}[x]$?

Isn't $x^4+1$ irreducible in $\mathbb{R}[x]$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$x^4+1=(x^2+\sqrt2 x+1)(x^2-\sqrt2 x+1)$$

More generally, if $f$ is a real polynomial with a 
non-real complex zero $\alpha$,
then $f$ has the irreducible real factor $(x-\alpha)(x-\overline\alpha)$.

Comment: Ohh I see thans!

Comment: Actually I don't get it. If $\alpha$ is complex then how is $(x-\alpha)$$ a real factor?

Comment: $x-\alpha$ **isn't** a real factor, but $(x-\alpha)(x-\overline\alpha)$ is @Loli

Comment: makes sense! i need some rest, i'm confusing myself with everything right now, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

First of all, any polynomial of *odd* degree in $\Bbb R[x]$ is reducible because it has a real root, by the intermediate value theorem.

Any polynomial of even degree greater than $2$ cannot be irreducible since $\Bbb C = \Bbb R(i)$ is an algebraic closure of $\Bbb R$ and an extension of degree $2$.

Comment: Do you happen to know all division $\mathbb{R}$-algebras?